# Qt C++ grammar?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning Qt, found this:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::WidgetClass)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

what is ": QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::WidgetClass)" mean?

And how can I get the C++ document about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is nothing special with Qt, just part of C++.

`: QWidget(parent)` is just calling the base contructor.

`ui(new Ui::WidgetClass)` is just a member being initialized.

Example:

```
class B
{
public:
  B(int x)
  {
    myx = x;
  }

  int myx;
};

class D : public B
{
public:
   D() 
   : B(4), p(new char[1024])
   {
   }

   ~D()
   {
     delete[] p;
   }

   char *p;
};
```

Comment: how can I get this reference? I only had watched this: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces.html

Comment: Most books on C++ programming will cover this

Answer (score 4):

The construct is called an **initialization list** and is used to initialize base classes and/or member variables in class constructors.

If you want to learn more about them (it's an essential concept in C++), see for example [this document](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) or [ask 'the' google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c%2B%2B+initialization+list).